# Is/Are there 50 sheep in the field?

Tags: grammar

Is there 50 sheep in the field? or Are there 50 sheep in the field?

Somehow, I think both are correct. But, I do not know for sure, which is why I am asking.

Thank you for any help, anyone

Answer (score 2):

**Are there 50 sheep in the field?** is correct because "sheep" is a plural noun (sheep - sing., sheep - pl.) used after "50". You wouldn't say "Is there 10 tables?", would you? For the same reason, say "are there 50 sheep in the field?"